# Ubuntu router using nftables blocking traffic

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nat, router, nftables

I'm trying to set up a simple router in Ubuntu. There are two network interfaces: eth0 - a wired network interface connected to the internet, and wlan0 - configured as an AP with IP address 10.0.9.1.

IPv4 forwarding is enabled.

I'm using dnsmasq with the following configuration:

```ini
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.9.2,10.0.9.30,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-host=40:a3:6b:c1:9a:54,10.0.9.100
```

The devices connect to my AP and get assigned IP addresses correctly.

Now configuring the NAT. My nftables config looks like this:

```ini
table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                iif "eth0" tcp dport 8010 dnat to 10.0.9.100:80
                iif "eth0" tcp dport 9001 dnat to 10.0.9.100:9001
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oif "eth0" masquerade
        }
}
```

This setup works as expected:

- Devices connected to wlan0 can reach the internet via eth0
- Devices connected to wlan0 can connect to a server on the router at 10.0.9.1
- Device with IP 10.0.9.1.100 can be reached on port 8010 and 9001 thru eth0

However, I'd like to set up a simple firewall to protect the devices from unauthorized access. This is what I have added to my nftables config:

```ini
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }
                iifname lo accept
                icmp type echo-request limit rate 5/second accept
                ip protocol icmp drop

                iif "eth0" tcp dport { ssh, 8080 } accept
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

                ct status dnat accept
                iif "wlan0" oif "wlan0" accept
                iif "wlan0" oif "eth0" accept
                iif "eth0" oif "wlan0" ct state established,related accept
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

This setup does not work as expected:

- Devices connected to wlan0 **can't** reach the internet via eth0
- Devices connected to wlan0 **can't** connect to a server on the router at 10.0.9.1
- Device with IP 10.0.9.1.100 can be reached on port 8010 and 9001 thru eth0

If I disable all protection in nfconfig it works as expected:

```ini
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

When I edit the `chain input` section, things stop working.

I'm completely new to nftables, and I have been spending the whole day trying to figure out how to get it working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *forward* chain does allow forwarding from the wireless LAN to Internet. What the whole ruleset doesn't allow, is to query *dnsmasq*'s builtin DNS server on the router from *wlan0*. This DNS server is configured by default for the clients in the DHCP part of *dnsmasq*.

Such DNS flow is not forwarded, so doesn't use the *forward* hook. It's an incoming flow received in the *input* hook. Without DNS, wireless nodes, while having connectivity to Internet, won't be able to resolve where to connect to, so the overall effect will appear the same: no Internet.

To allow router's services to be available when queried from *wlan0*, thus including DNS queries:

```
nft add rule inet filter input iif wlan0 accept
```

This will get the rate limitation for pings unless placed before the `ip protocol icmp` rule. Anyway this `ip protocol icmp drop` rule is otherwise not needed and could be removed since the default policy is already *drop*, unless intending to filter received traffic from wireless nodes.

If using (a) more restrictive rule(s) to allow only a few services, at least 53/TCP+UDP for DNS and port 67/UDP for DHCP in case *dnsmasq* doesn't rely completely on raw sockets for DHCP should be allowed from *wlan0*.